# How to login into my website via Facebook

Tags: php

I make my website to login via facebook. But I got these problem. How to solve this problem. Thanks your help.!

[Problem are show in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcAbF.jpg)
[image: Problem are show in link]

Comment: [enter application code to display what you tried so somebody can suggest a solution here]

Comment: display your code and error so we will help you and resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to connect to `255.255.255.255` I guess the problem is in one of the following:

- The URL in your FB application is configured with invalid name
- The host file on your local machine is not configured with the correct host name
- The DNS that you are using can not resolve the hostname that you placed in the FB App config

My advice is to simply use `localhost` as FB App domain while developing the site.